# Can I use public security groups in cloud formation for ec2 launch configs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Can I use public security groups in cloud formation for ec2 launch configs ?
I am trying to simply direct the cloudformation stack to use an existing set and it fails to create those resources.
I tried to create those security groups as a rolling set (ssh1,ssh2...) for each stack but no such luck either.

It would be really cool if your answer would include a code snippet as to how to do this exactly. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the sample template for deep understanding.

[Amazon EC2 instance in a security group](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-west-2/EC2InstanceWithSecurityGroupSample.template)

Here is the part you are interesting.

```
  "Resources" : {
    "EC2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "InstanceType" },
        "SecurityGroups" : [ { "Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup" } ],    # <--Here is the refer
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSRegionArch2AMI", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" },
                          { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "AWSInstanceType2Arch", { "Ref" : "InstanceType" }, "Arch" ] } ] }
      }
    },

    "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
          "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
          "FromPort" : "22",
          "ToPort" : "22",
          "CidrIp" : { "Ref" : "SSHLocation"}
        } ]
      }
    }
  },
```

Above sample to create a new security group, and assign it to a new ec2 instance. If you have exist security group, then you needn't the part `InstanceSecurityGroup`, and assign the real security group name to ec2 instance at:

```
"SecurityGroups" : "REAL Security Group Name",
```